# How to stop Mypy from raising when slicing DatetimeIndex dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, mypy

I have a dataframe with DatetimeIndex

```py
# hello_world.py
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1, 2, 3],
        "b": [1, 2, 3],
    },
    index=[
        dt.datetime(2020, 1, 1),
        dt.datetime(2021, 1, 1),
        dt.datetime(2022, 1, 1),
    ],
)


df.loc[dt.datetime(2021, 1, 1) :]
```

I'm getting this error when running mypy

```
hello_world.py:18: error: Slice index must be an integer or None
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I think you are missing a comma between `df.loc[dt.datetime(2021, 1, 1)` and  `:` so it should be `df.loc[dt.datetime(2021, 1, 1), :]` or what happens if you remove the `:` ?

Comment: @sksallaj I meant to slice the rows with index greater than `dt.datetime(2021, 1, 1)` - not just one particular row